# How to access shelved source code from diff machine?

Tags: tfs, shelving

I shelved some source code from one machine into TFS. Is there then a way to access that code from another machine via TFS, or is it only accessible from the machine from which it was shelved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely, choose "unshelve" and look up the code by your username.

"The menu is located at: File \ Source Control \ Unshelve Pending Changing" - from (John Dyer)

Comment: Beautiful! Took me a bit to find the command, but just what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @John Dyer - Thanks, I didn't know that particular shortcut.